# temporary failure in name resolution after replug the cable

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet, dhcp

I connect my laptop to Pi through direct cable, so that I can share wifi connection with Pi .Like this:

[image]

I went to Control Panel-->Network and Internet-->Network connections, right click on Wifi ,select properties, and check on option "allow other network users......" on sharing section.My Pi can successfully connect to the Internet after this set-up.

But it is just a laptop, I have to unplug the cable from time to time, move the laptop, carry it back, and replug the cable.

Strange thing occurs now.Every time when I replug the cable, my Pi lost the Internet connection. I can still ssh to Pi from laptop, but I can't connect to the Internet from Pi.

```
pi@raspberry:~$ ping -c3 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2042ms

pi@raspberry:~$ ping www.google.com
ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I tried edit /etc/resolv.conf, still not working.

```
pi@raspberry:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

After many tries, I simply turn off the "connection sharing option"from wifi properties ,and check on it again. Suddenly, Pi can successfully connect to the Internet! The problem just disappeared.
[image]

How is this happening? What should I do to solve the problem once and for all? I dont want to turn off and on the checkbox everytime.

Comment: This is a problem with the laptop - nothing to do with Pi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) service in Windows has a timeout of 5 minutes or so. After that the ICS service is terminated and will not be restarted unless you manually click on the checkbox again.

ICS can be made persistent by setting

```
HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedAccess\EnableRebootPersistConnection
```

parameter to 1 in the registry (create a new parameter of type `dword` if it doesn't exist), and changing the startup type of a service called `SharedAccess` to "Automatic" in

> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services

or by running `services.msc`.

Perhaps it will help with short disconnects (not reboots) as well, but I didn't try it myself.

Comment: Thanks! It works immediately.